# overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode) inside my Display templete does not have any effect

Tags: 2013, development, display-template, content-search-web-part

I found the following function `overrideValueRenderer` inside our custom display temple, as follow:-

```
    <mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Link URL':'Path'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>

<body>
    <div id="TwoLines">
<!--#_
// Give up your names for the properties in the following array
var linkURL = $getItemValue(ctx, "Link URL");
linkURL.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode);
```

now i am using this variable to build a `<a>` link, as follow:-

```
String.format("<a href='{0}' class='ms-listlink'>{1}</a>", linkURL, property)
```

But i am not sure what is the real purpose of the following function `.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode)` because i try rendering the following value inside my display templete :-

```
 _#= linkURL =#_
```

And i have noted that this value will always be the same regardless if i remove  the `linkURL.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode);` or i keep it.

For example i will always get this value for an `_#= linkURL =#_` , regardless of removing the `linkURL.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode);` or i keeping it:-

```
http://servername/sites/deptname/Lists/Discussion/test $£'
```

so seems the value of the url is not url-encoded,, So I am not sure what is the effect/purpose of the `overrideValueRenderer` function inside my display template ? logically the `linkURL.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode);`   should url encode the linkURL value,, but when i render the linkURL value i will get url that is not url encoded .. is this correct ?

Answer (score 2):

The `overrideValueRenderer` method will override value retrieved from the managed property.

For example, if the value of managed property of type text has large number of characters , so it will get trimmed and the value displayed would be (upto 90 characters + ellipsis).

In case, the managed property is giving us date/time value, this function will apply some logic on the value, format it , clean it and transform the value into a presentable date format.

In other cases, like this one `urlHtmlEncode`, it should give you back the trimmed, formatted and encoded url value. I think you can remove the line containing `overrideValueRenderer` in this case since encoding is not getting applied.

`overrideValueRenderer` is defined in the ***Search.Controls.debug.js*** and ***Search.Controls.js*** of the 15 hive. You can take look at its implementation in those js files.

Also check the below screenshot from a book, *Pro SharePoint 2013 Branding and Responsive Web Development* , which gives us some idea about what is happening here. Unfortunately, i cant find any official documentation for the same.

[image]

[OverrideValueRenderer](http://onlinecoder.blogspot.in/2014/01/override-value-renderer-in-display.html)

[Display Templates and wrong date formatting](http://www.sharepointappie.nl/display-templates-wrong-date-formatting/)

Comment: thanks for the reply. now you mentioned "_ I think you can remove the line containing overrideValueRenderer in this case since encoding is not getting applied._" but i do not think that this function which is defined in almost every display temple i have seen, does not have any effect... it should url encode the value,, but it is not doing so ... so is it a bug or i need to render the linkURL value in certain way to get it url encoded..

Comment: can you advice on my reply please?

Comment: Sorry for late replies. No it's not a bug, it looks like the url is already encoded (see above image in answer for desc) . Hence its not getting encoded again in the override function. However, if you think that the encoding is not working  you can  encode it using the OOTB function as:  `$urlHtmlEncode(linkURL);`

Comment: so you mean the url is already encoded , without the need to use `.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode)` sorry i did not get your point ??

Comment: and if i want to use `$urlHtmlEncode(linkURL);`  ,, then i could face a problem that the url is being encoded twice; one using `$urlHtmlEncode(linkURL);` and the other using the existing `.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode)`..  is this scenario valid ?

Comment: yes it's already encoded, thats what i believe and it's also mentioned in the book screenshot posted in the answer.   `linkURL = $urlHtmlEncode(linkURL);`  , if you are using this, then `.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode)` should be removed as its not necessary.

Comment: Couple of other points, just add the line `console.log(linkURL)` in the code to debug what URL is getting formed. Check the url in the browser to see if it's working or not.